# I Can't install Web3

Tags: npm, npm-install, web3js, linux-mint

I have to install Web3 which is a ethereum library but I can't install in linux mint 18.

```
$ sudo npm install web3 --save
[sudo] password for taylor: 
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/taylor/.npm/_logs/2018-02-01T12_55_24_014Z-debug.log
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly states that you are missing git.
Try installing git first and give it a go ?